# I'm getting a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' when app is hosted on Railway/Vercel

Tags: javascript, express, vercel, railway

I Have a MERN stack app that I'm trying to deploy.  The back-end is hosted on railway and front-end on Vercel.
It's using google OAuth 2.0 for authentication and express-sessions/connect-mongo for session storage.
When I run the app on my local machine, everything works fine but once its hosted on railway/Vercel, when I try to login,
it kicks me back to the login page and gives me the following error in the railway logs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at dashboard (/server/controllers/index.js:11:63)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
at next (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
at router (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

I think the `id` property is undefined because the `req.user` property is also undefined.
I feel like it has something to do with express-sessions or connect-mongo but I don't
fully understand how those packages work.
All I know is that one of them is suppose to add a user property to the req object that includes an id property at some point in the authentication process.

Here is my server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const cors = require("cors");
const flash = require("connect-flash");

//suppress mongoose deprecation warning
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

//Body parser config
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      process.env.HOST_NAME,
      process.env.PREVIEW_HOST,      
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

//database connection
connectDB();

//passport Config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

//sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI,
      collectionName: "sessions",
    }),
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
    },
  })
);

//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//routes
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/words", require("./routes/words"));
app.use("/materials", require("./routes/materials"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The error makes reference to my controllers/index.js

```js
const User = require("../models/User");
const Materials = require("../models/Materials");

module.exports = {
  getIndex: (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome");
  },
  dashboard: async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    try {
      const materials = await Materials.find({ user: req.user.id })
        .limit(4)
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
      const words = await User.find({ _id: req.user.id }, { wordList: 1 });
      res.json({ materials, words });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);

      res.json({ error: "Server Error" });
    }
  },
};
```

Here's a link to the repo on github: https://github.com/JaredCaprio/relink

I'm also getting a bunch of these warning in the Firefox console which made me think I needed to change the configuration of the express-sessions cookie.  So I tried changing the sameSite attribute to 'none' but I still got the same error.

```
Cookie “SIDCC” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
```

Comment: The error does not mean that the "id" property is undefined, it means that that `req.user` is undefined.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, I understand that.  I'm unable to determine why `req.user` is undefined once deployed to railway but not on my machine.